# AngularJS: Controller inheritance for components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

How to inherit controllers of [angular components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)? In the "old" angular I could use `$controller` or `$injector` but what shall I do with isolated scopes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $parent, $$childHead, $$childTail.

Though isolated scope don't inherit prototypically, they do have parent/child references

Comment: Thx for the answer, Kobi. Can you please post me a reference to the docs? I can't find any of the provided `$`s here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ .

Comment: please refer to this semi-official valuable resource https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: It looks good. During the week I will finish a component and I let you know if it solved my issue. Then I'd of course accept your answer.

Comment: sure enough, hope it would help

Comment: Please note that $$something is meant to be used by angular internally only. It is considered bad style to use it in your app. Nonetheless I am also searching for a solution for component controller inheritance.